# How can the log-in screen sound of linux mint 11 be changed?

Tags: audio, login, linux-mint

How can I customize the sound that occurs when the log-in screen pops up on linux mint 11?

Answer (score 1):

[Google revealed `Control Center -> Startup Applications Preferences -> GNOME Login Sound`](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=200&t=63968#p468758) and [maybe this is interesting, too](https://github.com/Nano77/gdm3setup).